# Botón app no funciona(¿sin error en log?)

Tags: mysql, xml, kotlin

tengo el código siguiente en kotlin, que quiero utilizar para hacer un login que conecte con una BD de  Mysql/MariaDB aparentemente funciona todo (no da error) pero al hacer click en el botón no hace nada. no encuentro donde esta el error, cabe decir que es mi primera app y mi primer desarrollo en kotlin.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.revisionesservigasa

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var username: EditText? = null
var password: EditText? = null
var newbuton: Button? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    username = findViewById(R.id.username)
    password = findViewById(R.id.password)
    newbuton = findViewById(R.id.newbuton)
    newbuton?.setOnClickListener {
        validarUsuario("https://intranet/login.php")
    }}
private fun validarUsuario(url: String) {
    val stringrequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(
        Method.POST.toString(),
        Response.Listener { response ->
            if (response.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"acceso concedido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, PrincipalActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
  } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()}},
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity,
                error.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()}) {
        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val parametros: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
            parametros["usuario"] = username!!.text.toString()
            parametros["password"] = password!!.text.toString()
            return parametros
        }}
    val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
    requestQueue.add(stringrequest)
    }}
```

PD: aunque pueda parecer pregunta duplicada ya he probado las respuestas/soluciones de otras preguntas parecidas y no me ha funcionado.

Comment: Falta información sobre la depuración. Se realiza la petición? Cuál es el código de respuesta? Qué toast se muestra? Hasta donde llega el flujo de ejecución? Lee cómo crear un [mre]

Comment: como he dicho en el titulo el botón directamente no funciona, no realiza petición, no hay respuesta, en el código va incluido un toast que al pulsar el botón aunque no hiciese el login debería poner "acceso concedido" pero directamente no hace nada es como si estuviese de adorno. por otra parte el código puesto es todo el código del login de mi proyecto, con un xml de login básico cambiando los ID deberías poder reproducir el login de la app

Comment: El ejemplo no es reproducible. Por empezar `https://intranet/login.php` no es una url válida. Sólo podría funcionar si es un alias dentro de tu red local. Y no podemos crear un servidor local porque no proporcionas el código del backend. Además tampoco mencionas cuál es el resultado esperado. Ni siquiera podemos verificar que el id del botón sea `R.id.newbuton`. Tal vez `findViewById()` retorna `null` y por lo tanto nunca se añade el clickListener. Vuelve a leer qué es un [mre]

Comment: Y dale un vistazo a la [documentación sobre cómo depurar](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#startdebug), te resultará muy útil.

Comment: comprobare que `findViewById()` no retorne null, por otra parte el codigo si es reproducible ya que la url es indiferente para la ejecucion basica y que al pulsar el boton retorne el  `toast` "mensaje concedido" o alguno de los `toast` de error o "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta" y como ya he dicho con un login de kotlin basico cambiando los id a username password y newbuton deberia funcionar de todos modos incluire el archivo xml en la pregunta y cambiare la url a la que estoy usando, tambien les proporcionare un usuario de pruebas temporal.

Comment: no se que hice que ya me funciona el botón, pero ahora me da un error bad URL `E/Volley: [314] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 1`

Answer (score 0):

ya esta resuelto el problema, era un parametro mal colocado en validar usuario

tenia puesto

```
private fun validarUsuario(url: String) {
val stringrequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(
    Method.POST.toString(),
    Response.Listener { response ->...
```

y tenia que poner

```
private fun validarUsuario(url: String) {
val stringrequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(
    Method.POST,
    URL,
    Response.Listener { response ->
```

eso era todo.